# How to define size of text field in ckeditor?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

While inserting text field in ckeditor by default it inserts `<input type="text" />` Is there any way we can insert like `<input type="text" size="5"/>`.By default it should insert defined size also.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add a text field to the dialog box or do you want to specify the size of the ckeditor?

For the size of the ckeditor I used: `<textarea cols="80" id="..." name="..." rows="10"></textarea>`

Not sure if you can use `<input type="text">`, but you can try to use cols and rows instead of size.